# Kubernetes Storage on bare-metal/private cloud

Tags: kubernetes, storage, persistent, kubernetes-pod

I'm just starting with Kubernetes on 2 node (master-minion) setup on 2 private cloud servers. I've installed it, did basic config and got it running some simple pods/services from the master to the minion.

**My question is:**

*How can I use persistent storage with the pods when not using Google Cloud?*

For my first tests I got a Ghost Blog pod running, but if i tear the pod the changes are lost. Tried adding volume to the pod, but can't actually find any documentation about how it is done when not on GC.

My try:

```
apiVersion: v1beta1
id: ghost
kind: Pod
desiredState:
  manifest:
    version: v1beta1
    id: ghost
    containers:
      - name: ghost
        image: ghost
        volumeMounts:
          - name: ghost-persistent-storage
            mountPath: /var/lib/ghost
        ports:
          - hostPort: 8080
            containerPort: 2368
    volumes:
      - name: ghost-persistent-storage
        source:
          emptyDir: {}
```

Found this: [Persistent Installation of MySQL and WordPress on Kubernetes](http://amygdala.github.io/kubernetes/2015/01/13/k8s1.html)

Can't figure it out how to add storage (NFS?) to my testing install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFS Example:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/volumes/nfs

GlusterFS Example:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/volumes/glusterfs

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, the NFS is the one I need. Gonna give it a shot today :)

Comment: Well got it working with nfs mount from the master to the pods, but when i restart the pod it deletes everything in the mounted directory :/

Answer (score 2):

In the new API ([v1beta3](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/api/v1beta3/types.go)), we've added many more volume types, including [NFS volumes](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/api/v1beta3/types.go#L217). The NFS volume type assumes you already have an NFS server running somewhere to point the pod at. Give it a shot and let us know if you have any problems!

Comment: The v1beta3 link is broken and I can only find v1. Please update the link, maybe with the commit id.

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://github.com/suquant/glusterd solution.

### Glusterfs server in kubernetes cluster

Idea very simple, cluster manager listen kubernetes api and add to /etc/hosts "metadata.name" and pod ip address.

#### 1. Create pods

gluster1.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: gluster1
  namespace: mynamespace
  labels:
    component: glusterfs-storage
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    host: st01
  containers:
    - name: glusterfs-server
      image: suquant/glusterd:3.6.kube
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      command:
        - /kubernetes-glusterd
      args:
        - --namespace
        - mynamespace
        - --labels
        - component=glusterfs-storage
      ports:
        - containerPort: 24007
        - containerPort: 24008
        - containerPort: 49152
        - containerPort: 38465
        - containerPort: 38466
        - containerPort: 38467
        - containerPort: 2049
        - containerPort: 111
        - containerPort: 111
          protocol: UDP
      volumeMounts:
        - name: brick
          mountPath: /mnt/brick
        - name: fuse
          mountPath: /dev/fuse
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/glusterd
      securityContext:
        capabilities:
          add:
            - SYS_ADMIN
            - MKNOD
  volumes:
    - name: brick
      hostPath:
        path: /opt/var/lib/brick1
    - name: fuse
      hostPath:
        path: /dev/fuse
    - name: data
      emptyDir: {}
```

gluster2.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: gluster2
  namespace: mynamespace
  labels:
    component: glusterfs-storage
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    host: st02
  containers:
    - name: glusterfs-server
      image: suquant/glusterd:3.6.kube
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      command:
        - /kubernetes-glusterd
      args:
        - --namespace
        - mynamespace
        - --labels
        - component=glusterfs-storage
      ports:
        - containerPort: 24007
        - containerPort: 24008
        - containerPort: 49152
        - containerPort: 38465
        - containerPort: 38466
        - containerPort: 38467
        - containerPort: 2049
        - containerPort: 111
        - containerPort: 111
          protocol: UDP
      volumeMounts:
        - name: brick
          mountPath: /mnt/brick
        - name: fuse
          mountPath: /dev/fuse
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/glusterd
      securityContext:
        capabilities:
          add:
            - SYS_ADMIN
            - MKNOD
  volumes:
    - name: brick
      hostPath:
        path: /opt/var/lib/brick1
    - name: fuse
      hostPath:
        path: /dev/fuse
    - name: data
      emptyDir: {}
```

#### 3. Run pods

```
kubectl create -f gluster1.yaml
kubectl create -f gluster2.yaml
```

#### 2. Manage glusterfs servers

```
kubectl --namespace=mynamespace exec -ti gluster1 -- sh -c "gluster peer probe gluster2"
kubectl --namespace=mynamespace exec -ti gluster1 -- sh -c "gluster peer status"
kubectl --namespace=mynamespace exec -ti gluster1 -- sh -c "gluster volume create media replica 2 transport tcp,rdma gluster1:/mnt/brick gluster2:/mnt/brick force"
kubectl --namespace=mynamespace exec -ti gluster1 -- sh -c "gluster volume start media"
```

#### 3. Usage

gluster-svc.yaml

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: glusterfs-storage
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  ports:
    - name: glusterfs-api
      port: 24007
      targetPort: 24007
    - name: glusterfs-infiniband
      port: 24008
      targetPort: 24008
    - name: glusterfs-brick0
      port: 49152
      targetPort: 49152
    - name: glusterfs-nfs-0
      port: 38465
      targetPort: 38465
    - name: glusterfs-nfs-1
      port: 38466
      targetPort: 38466
    - name: glusterfs-nfs-2
      port: 38467
      targetPort: 38467
    - name: nfs-rpc
      port: 111
      targetPort: 111
    - name: nfs-rpc-udp
      port: 111
      targetPort: 111
      protocol: UDP
    - name: nfs-portmap
      port: 2049
      targetPort: 2049
  selector:
    component: glusterfs-storage
```

Run service

```
kubectl create -f gluster-svc.yaml
```

After you can mount NFS in cluster by hostname "glusterfs-storage.mynamespace"